# Postgres not saving special characters

Tags: postgresql, psql

I am trying to reset password for all users with following psql command. The command executes successfully but the value of password is wrong. The password is bcrypt string of 12345

```
psql -U myuser -d mydb -c "update \"Users\" set \"PASSWORD\" = '$2a$10$u0vd9noCisUUJME9k4daU.1/TNBPaeQam8dnV6tUOWwjn4kFT5XdW'"
```

The query:

```
select "PASSWORD" from "Users";
```

returns:

```
a.1/TNBPaeQam8dnV6tUOWwjn4kFT5XdW
```

instead of:

```
$2a$10$u0vd9noCisUUJME9k4daU.1/TNBPaeQam8dnV6tUOWwjn4kFT5XdW
```

What I understand that postgres is taking $ as a placeholder or special character. How can I escape it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is not with postgres but with the shell. It interprets the dollar signs as beginning of variables. You should escape them wit a backslash (`'\$2a\$10\$u0vd9noCisUUJME9k4daU.1/TNBPaeQam8dnV6tUOWwjn4kFT5XdW'`):

```
psql -U myuser -d mydb -c "update \"Users\" set \"PASSWORD\" = '\$2a\$10\$u0vd9noCisUUJME9k4daU.1/TNBPaeQam8dnV6tUOWwjn4kFT5XdW'"
```

Comment: Bingo, thanks a lot @macmoonshine, works perfectly :)

Comment: You're wellcome. BTW.: The `pgcrypto` module from pgcontrib offers a stored function for this encryption as well.